# My question isn't on the newest questions tab

Tags: support

I asked a question on SO, and I checked the newest questions to make sure it was there (because you can't trust the system) and it wasn't there. So I refreshed the page and saw that it was there for a split second. So it shows up but then disappears in less then a second. I have only 8 rep on the site and I've gotten lots of downvotes on some questions, even to the point where I was banned from asking for a period of time. I'm guessing this is because it needs moderator review or something of the sort?

Comment: Is this answered on another meta question?  I think the underlying question is *What causes a new question to sometimes not show on a question list until it's about 1 minute old?*  I've noticed this - sometimes a page refresh will "vanish" a seconds-old question, only to reappear a minute later.

Comment: Yea, your guess could be right. Maybe it had to make it through the Triage queue before being displayed.

Comment: Which page are we talking about specifically here? The 'newest' tab on a specific tag? In any case yes, it is very likely that your question entered a review queue - not necessarily a moderator one, in fact very unlikely it was a moderator queue. The SO help has information on the privileges you can earn, including reviewing: http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/access-review-queues

Comment: For what it's worth, I've seen questions in the newest tab and in Triage at the same time.